# Categorization of text in Excel

Tags: excel, search, text, full-text-search, categorization

I have to do a categorization based on in-text search in Excel.

1) There is a text description of an idea. 
2) I want to search for the existence of one key word from a list of 4-5 words. These words will be in different cells (For example, four words 1) Video 2) TV 3) Mobile and 4) YouTube). The category these key words represent is "Entertainment."
3) In case there is a match of key word in the description, I want to return the name of the category.

Here is the same process which examples

Description: Watching videos of my mobile is the biggest time pass"
Key words: video videos
Category: If any of the above words appear in the description, categorize it as "Entertainment"

I have tried to do it using Index / Match however get stuck as it is not a single word I am looking for :)

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2):

Index-Match in an array formula will work. Here is an array formula which will do the job.

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,IFNA(MATCH("*"&$D$1:$D$7&"*",A2,0),0),0))
```

Array formulas need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter and the curly braces will be inserted by Excel if done right.

Note that this formula will get the first occuring match as can be observed for the text "Basketball video".

[image]

Comment: Hi eshwar, Thank you very much for your reply. I am following this but getting a #Name? error. My data (Text, as per your column headings) is not in English and I think that shouldn't matter. However, each cell in Text column is quite long (200+ characters). I wrote key words from this text in Column D, and then followed the same procedure, but get the #Name? error. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hi eshwar, I get a #NAME? even when I try to replicate your results.

Comment: #Name indicates you have not entered the formula correctly